# How to show results even if the user did not choose from all select boxes?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a search form that displays in "results.php" the matched rows from MySQL. I have some select boxes to let the user select his preferences. However, the user may not choose from all the select boxes but from a few. If this happens, my query will return nothing because it is supposed to use all the available choices.

For example, the only must variable to choose is the `make`. `disabled` is standard and I need it in every query.

How can I edit the following to "remove the `AND model = '$model'` when `model` is not choosed and `AND year = '$year'` when `year` is not choosed?

I will use the example for more choices.

```
$make = $_POST["make"];
$model = $_POST["model"];
$year = $_POST["year"];
$useds = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM used WHERE make = '$make' AND model = '$model' AND year = '$year' AND disabled='0' order by id desc" );
```

Comment: Your script is probably [prone to SQL injections](http://bobby-tables.com) and also [the mysql extension is deprecated](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php). You should switch to [MySQLi](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) and use prepared statements.

Comment: How many makes and models are we talking about here?

Answer (score 1):

Build the query up in pieces and then thread it together. You benefit from the fact that at least one of the where clauses is compulsory. I am using short IF syntax but you could write it out fully using `if(){}else{}` if you really wanted to.

```
$make  = ( isset($_POST['make']  ? 'make='.$_POST['make'].' AND '   : '' );
$model = ( isset($_POST['model'] ? 'model='.$_POST['model'].' AND ' : '' );
$year  = ( isset($_POST['year']  ? 'year='.$_POST['year'].' AND '   : '' );

$query = "SELECT * FROM used WHERE ".$make.$model.$year."disabled=0 ORDER BY id DESC"
$useds = mysql_query(" ");
```

The first three lines see if the posts were set, and if they are it turns them from $val to `col=$val AND`. If they are not then the variable is set as `''` and they insertion of that variable into the query has no effect.

```
$variable = ( true ? 'yes' : 'no' );
$variable = ( false? 'yes' : 'no' );
```

The first one gives you 'yes', the second 'no'

Then by stringing them together in the query, you can have any amount of them being used in the query:

```
WHERE make=$make AND disabled=0
WHERE make=$make AND model=$model AND disabled=0
WHERE make=$make AND model=$model AND year=$year AND disabled=0
WHERE year=$year AND disabled=0
```

If you're going to capitalize MySQL operators/functions then you should be consistent too so that you can tell which are names and which are not.

Answer (score 0):

You've got the cart before the horse. Do it vice versa: **Append** the conditions *if they are* selected.

```
$conditions = array();
$conditions[] = "make = '".mysql_real_escape_string($make)."'";
if (!empty($model)) $conditions[] = "model = '".mysql_real_escape_string($model)."'";
if (!empty($year)) $conditions[] = "year = '".mysql_real_escape_string($year)."'";
$conditions[] = "disabled = 0";
$conditionString = "WHERE ".implode(' AND ', $conditions);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM used ".$conditionString." ORDER BY id DESC";
```

Answer (score -1):

```
    $make = $_POST["make"];
    $model = $_POST["model"];
    $year = $_POST["year"];

   $query="SELECT * FROM used WHERE make = '$make'";
   if($model)
   $query.=" AND model = '$model'";
   if($year)
   $query.=" AND year = '$year'";

   $query.= " AND disabled='0' order by id desc";

  $useds = mysql_query($query);
```

Comment: I think someone gave you a downvote because you've replicated the SQL injection vulnerability in the OP's post. I take the view that, if you answer, it is worth being aware of this kind of mistake, so the OP can be advised how to run the query safely.

Comment: @halfer i know, i could try to secure the variables, but i think that is problem of OP to secure his code.